# Bash - Rewriting the if function

Tags: bash, if-statement, url-rewriting

I'm trying to make my own if function, which is written a little differently than the conventional if function.

This is what I currently have (which is probably very far from completion)

```
function check
{
    if [ "$2" = "=" ]; then
        if [ "$1" = "$3" ]; then
            // Don't know what to put in here
        elif [ "$1" != "$3" ]; then
            // Don't know what to put in here
        fi
    elif [ "$2" = "!=" ]; then
        if [ "$1" != "$3" ]; then
            // Don't know what to put in here
        elif [ "$1" = "$3" ]; then
            // Don't know what to put in here   
        fi
    fi
}
```

When completed it should run like:

```
check $foo != 2
    //do this
end
```

How do I achieve this?

How do I incorporate the indented code? And how do I incorporate the "end" statement?

Comment: You can't define new syntax in `bash`.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Prescription: Learn bash's syntax, instead of trying to tweak it.

Comment: I've done this before, not with if, but echo, cat, exit, and many others. Redefined how you define a variable, I think there is also a way to redefine if. Note: I used different names for those new functions... Perhaps I shouldn't call mine if?

Comment: I renamed the function to check.

Comment: `if` is not a command or a built-in function; it's a reserved word that introduces a syntactic construct.

Comment: Also, you didn't redefine how to define a variable; you wrote a wrapper around `bash`'s built-in `declare` command. Like `if`, parameter assignment is a syntactic feature which cannot be overridden in the shell language itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you're trying to do is better done by replacing `test` aka `[`, not `if` itself. Here's how you'd complete your function:

```
function check
{
    if [ "$2" = "=" ]; then
        if [ "$1" = "$3" ]; then
            return 0
        else 
            return 1
        fi
    elif [ "$2" = "!=" ]; then
        if [ "$1" != "$3" ]; then
            return 0
        else
            return 1
        fi
    fi
    echo "Unknown operator: $2" >&2
    return 1
}
```

And here's how to use it:

```
if check "foo" != "bar"
then
    echo "it works"
fi
```

Comment: No, based on his explanation, he really *is* trying to replace `if`.  He wants his `// do this` section to run when the condition is true, and since bash can't pass code blocks around like that, it's impossible to do what he's asking.

Comment: Actually, that is quite what I had in mind! However, when I run it it tells me `fi' is an unexpected token, and crashes........

Comment: @Leviathan make sure you have the `then` included, and that there is a line feed before both `then` and `fi`

Answer (score 0):

You will never succeed to create in bash a wrapper for `if`. This because `if` is a shell keyword.

> A *keyword* is a *reserved* word, token or operator. Keywords have a
>   special meaning to the shell, and indeed are the building blocks of
>   the shell's syntax. As examples, *if*, *for*, *while*, do, and *!* are keywords.
>   Similar to a [builtin](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internal.html#BUILTINREF), a keyword is hard-coded into Bash, but unlike a
>   *builtin*, a keyword is not in itself a command, but a *subunit of a
>   command construct*.

Here is a demonstration:

```
$ type if
if is a shell keyword
$ function if { echo "something"; }
$ type if
if is a shell keyword
$ #so, 'if' has remained a shell keyword
$ #and the new created function 'if' will never work :(
$ type cd
cd is a shell builtin
$ function cd { echo "something"; }
$ type cd
cd is a function
cd () 
{ 
    echo "something"
}
$ cd $HOME
something
$ #so, 'cd' is not anymore a builtin and the new created function 'cd' works! :)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response... What I'm trying to do is make a function which runs just like if, but has a different syntax... It basically takes the parameters, runs if on those parameters, and then runs the rest of the code. Taken from what you just gave me, this would be impossible?

Comment: @Leviathan As I said, **`if`** ***is not a function, or command, or builtin*** as you think. Is a syntactic feature which cannot be overridden in the shell language itself. So, you simply cannot to create something else like it